How can we derive this integral inequality?
Furthermore, let

$(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space;
$\mu$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$;
$\zeta$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$;
$\pi$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ with density $p$ with respect to $\lambda$;
$c>0$ and $\ell\in[0,1]$

Moreover, let $$\alpha(x,y):=\left.\begin{cases}\min\left(1,\displaystyle\frac{p(y)}{p(x)}\right)&\text{, if }p(x)>0\\1&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in E$$ and $$Q_\ell(x,B):=\ell\mu(B)+(1-\ell)\zeta(x,B)\;\;\;\text{for }(x,B)\in\mathcal E\times\mathcal E.$$ Now, let $\kappa_\ell$ denote the transition kernel of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal kernel $Q_\ell$ and target distribution $\pi$. That is, $$(\kappa_\ell f)(x)=f(x)+\underbrace{\int Q_\ell(x,{\rm d}y)\alpha(x,y)(f(y)-f(x))}_{=:\;(K_\ell f)(x)}\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E$$ for all bounded $\mathcal E$-measurable $f:E\to\mathbb R$.
Lastly, let $$\mathcal E(f):=\langle f,f-\zeta f\rangle_{L^2(\pi)}+c\langle f,f-\mu f\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}$$ and $$\mathcal E_\ell(f):=\langle f,f-\kappa_\ell f\rangle_{L^2(\pi)}$$ for bounded $\mathcal E$-measurable $f:E\to\mathbb R$.
Question How can we show that for $$W(R):=\inf\left\{\frac{R(f)}{\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\pi)}^2}:f\in L^2(\pi)\text{ with }\pi f=0\right\}$$ it holds $$W(\mathcal E)\le W(\mathcal E_\ell)?\tag1$$ If possible, I would actually even want to show "$<$".
Even though this would be stronger than what I'm asking for, what I've tried is to show that \begin{equation}\begin{split}\mathcal E(f)-\mathcal E_\ell(f)&=c\langle f,f-\mu f\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}-\ell\langle f,K_1f\rangle_{L^2(\pi)}\\&+\langle f,f-\zeta f\rangle_{L^2(\pi)}-(1-\ell)\langle f,K_0f\rangle_{L^2(\pi)}\end{split}\tag2\end{equation} is nonnegative (or, better, even positive) for all $f\in L^2(\pi)$.
However, I'm stuck with this. Another approach would be to construct a specific $f$ and show that for this $f$ $\mathcal E(f)$ is smaller than $\mathcal E_\ell(g)$ for a generic $g$.

If you want to think of an example, the one I'm particularly interested is the following:

$E[0,1)^d$ for some $d\in\mathbb N$;
$\mathcal E=\mathcal B([0,1)^d)$;
$\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1)^d$;
$\mu$ be the uniform distribution on $[0,1)^d$ (i.e. $\mu=\lambda$);
$\zeta(x,\;\cdot\;)$ be the wrapped normal distribution on $[0,1)^d$ with mean $x$ and covariance $\sigma^2I_d$ for some $\sigma>0$;
$c=1$.


The $L^2(\mu)$ in the second summand of the definition of $\mathcal E(f)$ is not a typo.
